# Linux security training?

Tags: linux

Can anybody please advise me of a training company/firm in London that offers good and recognised training in Linux security? I am interested particularly in Redhat Enterprise.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 2):

Learning Tree in Euston. Course 433 may be applicable.

Comment: Thanks Roy, it did come up in google but I've never tried them although I vaguely remember hearing about them before. Have you ever tried them?

Comment: I have a few weeks worth of training with them. Both in London and New York. I think they are allright. Their teachers work as consulants most of the time, which means they have real world experience and know a little on top of the text book material. I haven't been to their security courses, but I expect them to of similar standard.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to do some light reading beforehand, [www.sans.org](http://www.sans.org/) has some excellent whitepapers on securing linux.